# C++: Convert occurrences of hexadecimal ascii values in a string to normal chars

Tags: c++, ascii

I have a std::string which contains letters and numbers as normal, but all punctuation (e.g. brackets, square brackets, commas and colons) are in their ASCII representation (e.g. `%28`, `%29`, `%2C` and `%3A`).

What would be the fastest way to parse my string, leave 'normal' characters alone and convert hexadecimal values to their ASCII representations?

Comment: Why so concerned about the fastest way? I mean I could post an answer that worked, but it might not be the fastest way.

Comment: did you try to look at code of printf(format,str) 's format string parsing? There must be an algorithm in one of the printf.asm(or what ever it is) written in c++. Better luck in VC++ 10.0

Comment: There's one url decoder here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/server3/request_handler.cpp

Answer (score 2):

You could use e.g. the [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) function to search for the `'%'` character. If the next two characters are hexadecimal digits then replace the three characters with the actual character. Do all this in a loop while you find `'%'`.

Instead of doing in-place replacement, you could iterate over the string, appending normal characters to another string, and when you reach a `'%'` you check that it's a valid URL escape, and append the proper character to the output string.

Answer (score 1):

libcurl has the function [curl_easy_unescape](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_unescape.html):

```
char *curl_easy_unescape( CURL * curl , char * url , 
        int inlength , int * outlength );
```

> This function converts the given URL encoded input string to a "plain
>   string" and returns that in an allocated memory area. All input
>   characters that are URL encoded (%XX where XX is a two-digit
>   hexadecimal number) are converted to their binary versions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an in-place version:

```
void unescape(std::string & s)
{
    for (std::size_t r = 0, w = 0; r != s.size(); )
    {
        char digit;

        if (s[r] != '%')
        {
            ++r;
            ++w;
        }
        else if (r + 1 < s.size() && s[r + 1] == '%')
        {
            r += 2;
            ++w;
        }
        else if (r + 2 < s.size()) && is_hex(s, r + 1, digit))
        {
            s[w] = digit;
            ++w;
            r += 3;
        }
        else
        {
            // error, throw exception?
        }
    }

    s.erase(s.begin() + r, s.end());
}

bool is_hex(std::string const & s, std::size_t offset, char & result)
{
    unsigned char d1, d2;
    if (hex_digit(s[offset], d1) && hex_digit(s[offset + 1], d2))
    {
        result = d1 * 16 + d2;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

bool hex_digit(char c, unsigned char & value)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') { value = c - '0'; return true; }

    if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') { value = c - 'a' + 10; return true; }

    if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') { value = c - 'A' + 10; return true; }

    return false;
}
```